# Not able to build with expo react native 0.73.3

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, expo

Getting issues inside expo with expo bare workflow

expo/android/build.gradle' line: 169

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo'.

> Could not find method getModulesConfig() for arguments [] on task ':expo:generateExpoModulesPackageList' of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask.

Expo version  - "expo": "^50.0.4"
"expo": "^50.0.4",
"expo-app-loading": "^1.1.2",
"expo-build-properties": "^0.11.0",
"expo-constants": "^15.4.5",
"expo-font": "^11.10.2",
"expo-keep-awake": "^12.8.2",
"expo-notifications": "^0.27.6",
"expo-permissions": "^14.4.0",
"expo-secure-store": "^12.8.1",
"expo-sharing": "^11.10.0",
"expo-splash-screen": "^0.26.4",
"expo-status-bar": "^1.11.1",
"expo-updates": "^0.24.9",

All these are installed but this weird error for getModulesConfig() isn't allowing application to run on Android. What can be issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed expo's build.gradle from

```
def modulesConfig = getModulesConfig()
def outputPath = getGenerateExpoModulesPackagesListPath()
if (modulesConfig) {
  outputs.file(file(outputPath))
  inputs.property("modulesConfig", modulesConfig)
}

doLast {
  generateExpoModulesPackageList()
}
}

to 

task generateExpoModulesPackageList {
doLast {
  generateExpoModulesPackageList()
}
}

and it resolved the issue.
```